# How to detect if shading or tinting exists on an image?

Tags: javascript, colors, imagemagick, node-imagemagick

I want to count solid colors available on an image for silkscreen printing, and limit to maximum of 10 colors per design such how [teespring](http://answers.teespring.com/customer/portal/articles/1714421-upload-error) did.

I've tried numbers of techniques to count unique colors using javascript ([colorthief](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/)) and imagemagick. However the results are not suitable for this purpose because it also takes into account all colors exists on shading or tinting.

[image]

Example for image above, colorthief returning 9 unique colors. But if set the limit to 100, it returned as below.

```
var palette = colorThief.getPalette(image, 100);
```

[image]

So i would like to know how to detect the design if it has less than 10 colors or not?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with JavaScript. You need to check colorThiefs API.

Comment: Hi @StephanKristyn, I'm open to any other solution. not necessarily colorthief API only. I've also tried solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792385/how-to-count-color-on-image-using-html-canvas-getimagedata) but the results are the same. they successfully get unique colors out of the image. but what i want is how to detect if the image has solid colors less than 10. or maybe theres a way to detect existing of gradient or shades in the image

Comment: I think what I am trying to say is that you should ammend your question to be specific about a software development problem you have, e.g. help with a certain part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from your question whether you like or dislike what teespring or ColorThief does or what the problem is, or why you ask for 100 colours when you want 10, or if you think the 100 colours are wrong, or right... so I'll just try and suggest ways of getting the colours and you can see if you like them or not. As you are open to other tools, I'll choose ImageMagick which is available for OSX, Linux and Windows.

So, starting with your image, you can ask ImageMagick, at the command line, to choose its idea of the 10 best colours, and then to make them into a swatch of just those colours and resize it up from 10px by 1px to 500 pixels so you can see it:

```
convert motor.png -colors 10 -unique-colors -scale 500x swatch.png
```

[image]

Or, you could ImageMagick to quantise in the YIQ colorspace, like this:

```
convert motor.png -quantize YIQ -colors 10 -unique-colors -scale 500x swatch.png
```

[image]

Or, if you want the colour selection algorithm to ignore variations in saturation when choosing colours, you could go to HSL colorspace and fix the Saturation at say 50% leaving the Hues and Lightnesses unaffected and then go back to RGB colorspace and choose colours as above but now with fixed Saturation:

```
convert motor.png -colorspace hsl -channel G -fx 0.5 +channel -colorspace RGB -colors 10 -unique-colors -scale 500x swatch.png
```

[image]

Comment: Hi mark, to answer your question short, what i want is to do what teespring able to do which is to detect if the image is less than 10 or not. if i convert the image to limit the colors to 10 (`convert car.jpg +dither -colors 10 car_2.jpg` which resulted image like [this](http://s30.postimg.org/6t4zm54z5/412_1.jpg) teespring will accept it.

Comment: Huh? Sorry, I still don't understand. If that command in your comment above works, just use that. You don't need me.

Comment: I dont want a command to convert image into 10 colors, I want a command to detect how many colors the image has. Command `identify -format "%k" car_2.jpg` returned 515 unique colors for [this image (which previously converted to +dither -colors 10)](http://s18.postimg.org/ily1kkmbd/car_2.jpg). But I wonder how teespring detect it right?

Comment: If you run `convert car_2.jpg +dither -colors 10 d10car.png` and then run `convert d10car.png -format %k  info:`, you will see that it does indeed reduce the number of colours to 10. However, you chose JPEG as your format which not a good idea as it introduces lots of *errors* and inaccuracies to save space.